# No contents on odoo localhost

Tags: localhost, odoo

when I run odoo on local host,that what appears ,without the rest of the page

[odoo on local host8069](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7pIT.png)

[Here is the output of code , there are some errors, but I don't know what to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqbCU.png)

Comment: Can you check you odoo log? May be you can find something there.

Comment: please post your trace log which are currently running form the terminal and add it in your question

Comment: Where do I look to find odoo log?

Comment: I have editted the post

Comment: okey good but check your current python version from terminal

Answer (score 0):

Some times it Happens, Just Refresh the Page using Ctrl+F5, still its not loading then, check the Log in Terminal, may be some module which ever you are trying to load having some Issue in XML File.

Comment: Murali Krishna Reddy:

I have refreshed it several times ,but still not loading,where do I look to find odoo log?